# A problem with the command \nccurve

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, psmatrix

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node} % required package
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}    
\psmatrix[linecolor=red,mnode=Circle,radius=3mm,colsep=1.25cm,rowsep=1.25cm]
   [name=2] 2 &  & [name=3] 3 \\
              &[name=5] 5 \\
   [name=1] 1 &  & [name=4] 4
\psset{linecolor=blue,arrowscale=1.5}

\ncline{->}{3}{2}
\ncline{->}{4}{3}
\ncline{->}{4}{5} 
\ncline{->}{5}{3}
\ncline{->}{5}{1}
\ncline{->}{1}{4}

\nccurve[angleA=80,angleB=25,ncurv=5]{->}{3}{3}

\ncarc[arcangle=22]{->}{1}{2}
\ncarc[arcangle=22]{->}{2}{1}
\endpsmatrix 

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

How to draw **Picture 1** like as **Picture 2**?(I see, 2 is more beautiful than 1)

How to compact `\ncline` or we can only typing manually? It means is there a macro like as `\ncline{->}{3}{2}{->}{4}{3}{->}{4}{5}...` ?

**Picture 1**:

[image]

**Picture 2**:

[image]

The code of Picture 2 ( use tikz )

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={circle,draw=red},
 every path/.style={blue,-latex,thick}]
\def\a{2}
\node (5) at (0,0) {$5$};
\node (1) at (-\a,-\a) {$1$};
\node (2) at (-\a,\a) {$2$};
\node (3) at (\a,\a) {$3$};
\node (4) at (\a,-\a) {$4$};
\draw (1)--(4); \draw (4)--(3);
\draw (3)--(2); \draw (5)--(3);
\draw (5)--(1); \draw (4)--(5);
\draw (2) to[out=-70,in=70] (1);
\draw (1) to[out=110,in=-110] (2);
\draw (3) .. controls +(80:1) and +(30:1) .. (3); % <<<---- notice!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please improve question title.

Comment: :)))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: I assume you mean here that picture 2 (though hard to see that it are 2 pictures as they are in the output very close to one another) is nicer, in your eyse, than picture 1. In what respect ? What is the difference in the generation of picture 1 and picture 2?

Comment: I don't know the difference in the generation between them. :-)). I only hope anyone improve its macro "\nccurve[angleA=80,angleB=25,ncurv=5]{->}{3}{3}". ;))

Comment: Can you change the title to reflect which problem you have? At the moment it won't help any future users who might have the same problem as you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

define your own macro and for the loop use symmetrical angles with respect to 45 degrees::

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node} % required package
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand\NCline[3]{\ncline{#1}{#2}{#3}\@ifnextchar\bgroup\NCline{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \psmatrix[linecolor=red,mnode=Circle,radius=3mm,colsep=1.25cm,rowsep=1.25cm]
    [name=2] 2 &            & [name=3] 3 \\
               &[name=5] 5 \\
    [name=1] 1 &            & [name=4] 4
\psset{linecolor=blue,arrowscale=1.5}
\NCline{->}{3}{2}{->}{4}{3}{->}{4}{5}{->}{5}{3}{->}{5}{1}{->}{1}{4}
\nccurve[angleA=75,angleB=15,ncurv=6]{->}{3}{3}

\ncarc[arcangle=22]{->}{1}{2}
\ncarc[arcangle=22]{->}{2}{1}
\endpsmatrix 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you think about its the tikz code?. ( I see its code "shorter" but "complete" :-(( .The pstricks code is longer, more complex than or the reason my code is not enough short as it ). See my editted comment

Comment: sure, it has absolute coordinates for the nodes! Can also be done with PSTricks.